# Missing android.net.sip

Tags: android, mono, xamarin.android, sip

I have the following versions of Andorid and Java SDKs in the following environment.

I am trying to develop a SIP application but while Android.net.http and Android.net.wifi are both present, the needed Android.net.sip doesn't appear.

I'm assuming that this has something to do with the android SDK (version or perhaps mismatch to Java SDK version) but I haven't been able to find any information on this type of issue or much in general on SIP application support in Mono.

I'd appreciate if it someone can steer me in a direction in terms of finding the problem of the missing .sip assembly.

MonoDevelop 3.0.3.2

Installation UUID: 6e3978d7-9762-4c5a-80ee-c19e6a271794

Runtime:

```
Microsoft .NET 4.0.30319.269

GTK 2.16.6

GTK# (2.12.0.0)
```

Mono for Android: 4.2.3.68199851

Android SDK: C:\Android\android_sdk\android-sdk

Supported Android versions:

```
Version: 1.6    ApiLevel: 4

Version: 2.1    ApiLevel: 7

Version: 2.2    ApiLevel: 8

Version: 2.3    ApiLevel: 10

Version: 3.1    ApiLevel: 12

Version: 4.0    ApiLevel: 14

Version: 4.0.3  ApiLevel: 15
```

Java SDK: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_27\bin

No build info

Operating System:

```
Windows 6.1.7601.65536 (64-bit)
```

Comment: Updated with Android SDK Manager from version 4.0.3 API Level 15 to version 4.1 API Level 16 with no effect: Android.net.sip is still not found. Android documentation shows that android.net.sip has been in the API since Level 9.

Answer (score 1):

Answered my question by looking at my comment. I had the compatibility level set to 2.2 which was obviously before API level 9. Set the compatibility level up to 2.2.5 (API Level 9) and everything showed up.